# Trying to pass an argument to a function, can get through the ''@app.route'' in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass an argument to a function I made into app.route.

In the following code, I create 2 pages, 1 Homepage and 1 Admin page.
I want to permit or deny access to the /admin page depending if I have the parameter ADMINpass set to False or True in my python code directly.
I understand that in this particular situation, it will work, as I don't need to pass the argument, but if I define my admin page in another subscript and import it in mainscript, it will tell me that ''admin takes exactly 1 argument (0 given). So I want this function to work for whatever case.

I don't really worry about security for now as I am testing things.
Thanks alot and apologies if a similar question has already been posted. Here is the code:

```
###User section, importing parameters
ADMINpass=False
###End of user section

##Main code
@app.route('/') #Home page
def homepage():
   return 'Hello, main page here'


@app.route('/admin') #Admin page that I want to access
def admin(ADMINpass):  #Trying to pass the argument here will not work, probably because of the app.route
   if ADMINpass==False:    #If admin not activated in code, redirect to homepage
      a=redirect(url_for('homepage'))  
   if ADMINpass == True:  #If admin is activated, permit access
      print('This is the admin page')

if __name__== '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: You haven't included the parenthesis at the end of `app.run()` , that means the function is never called.

Comment: Hey Jasmijn, thanks, but I did include it in my code, just forgot to write it here, I'm gonna edit my text. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: What do you mean by "User section"? Is that part of the same module as the admin route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here.

The `@app.route` decorator is a wrapper around the admin() function. It provides the extra functionality that does route registration (the thing that allows the '/admin' string to be an endpoint), request handling (you could specify HTTP methods like 'POST' with it), and more (see [Flask docs for route()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#url-route-registrations)).

So if you did this:

```py
@app.route('/admin') #Admin page that I want to access
def admin(ADMINpass):  #Trying to pass the argument here will not work, probably because of the app.route
```

Flask expects you to use this for parameterising the endpoint itself:

```py
@app.route('/endpoint/<something>')
def func(something):
    return something
```

```sh
$ curl localhost:5000/endpoint/value_of_something
value_of_something
```

I would suggest [Miguel Grinberg's guide to decorators](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-ultimate-guide-to-python-decorators-part-i-function-registration) for more info on decorators with a focus on Flask.

Coming back to your issue, you could do this (but read on to see why I think you shouldn't):

```py
ADMINpass=False
@app.route('/endpoint')
def admin():
  global ADMINpass
  return f'ADMINpass is {ADMINpass}'
```

The problem with global variables is that they could be changed at any point in some other piece of code. This is generally a good way to introduce mistakes in your code and make your code less maintainable and more difficult to test.

With servers, the problem is more fundamental - what if your code grew to look something like this?

```py
ADMINpass=False
@app.route('/endpoint')
def admin():
    global ADMINpass
    ADMINpass = not ADMINpass
    return f'ADMINpass is {ADMINpass}'
```

Every request (which may be coming from different clients) would change it, so its value is nearly impossible to reason about:

```
$ curl localhost:5000/endpoint
ADMINpass is False
$ curl localhost:5000/endpoint
ADMINpass is True
$ curl localhost:5000/endpoint
ADMINpass is False
```

You might be looking for [Flask session objects](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#sessions). The values stored in the session object are specific to each client because its implementation is based on cookies. If it's an authentication mechanism implementation you're going towards, this may be exactly what you need.

```py
from flask import session
app.something = 'value_of_something_else'
@app.route('/endpoint')
def admin():
   return app.something
```

```sh
$ curl localhost:5000/endpoint
value_of_something_else
```

If a single static value is what you need, one way to overcome the errors you're likely getting when trying to use the variable would be to use a function you can always call:

```py
def admin_pass():
    return False
```

```py
@app.route('/endpoint')
def admin():
    if not admin_pass():
        ...
```